# Understanding Ruby While loops

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I am trying to figure out why my while loop isn't exiting when I want it to. 
Basically I am making a simple game where 2 players play words and get points each round if they play an allowed word. Once one player plays a word that ends in a particular character, that player loses the game.

The way I did it, is set a value to false (before the loop), and then use a while loop to keep the game going until a player inputs a losing word, at which point the loop should immediately exit, without going to player 2 (which at the moment it does). 
Here is essentially what I have now (at this point I am just trying to get the basic logic going):

```
player1_count = 0
player2_count = 0

continue = true

while continue
## get input
  if player1_input[-1] == losing_char
    continue = false
  else
    player1_count += 1
  end
##do the same for player 2
## get input
  if player2_input[-1] == losing_char
    continue = false
  else
    player2_count += 1
  end
end
```

The issue that I am having, is that I expected that when **continue** was set to false, the loop would terminate immediately, while instead it continues until the end of current run through the loop, getting player 2's input as well (if player 1 lost), which I don't want. I'm guessing that either I had the wrong idea about how loops work in Ruby, or I messed up somewhere in writing the loop/ used it wrongly.

Is there a way to write the while loop where it will keep going, until my **continue** variable is set to false, and have it exit right away as I am hoping?

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby (and all C-style languages), the while loop condition is only checked at the beginning of an iteration. This is by design, or else it would have to check the condition after each statement is run.

In this case, instead of using a continue variable, you should call `break`, which will exit the (innermost) loop immediately. So for your code

```
player1_count = 0
player2_count = 0

while true
## get input
  if player1_input[-1] == losing_char
    break
  else
    player1_count += 1
  end
##do the same for player 2
## get input
  if player2_input[-1] == losing_char
    break
  else
    player2_count += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: You could use the more idiomatic `loop do` instead of `while true`. And I would remove `else` and use an modifier-if instead, i.e. `break if player1_input[-1] == losing_char`.

Comment: Indeed these would both be more idiomatic, but I wanted to keep it simple since OP seems new to ruby